# How do I get token ID for my google smart home action through AWS API Gateway and AWS lambda in node js?

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, aws-lambda, action

I have created Smart Home with Actions on Google.User access it from google assistant and logs in to spike bot. Now I want the Token ID of oauth user.
AWS API Gateway and AWS lambda used for the same. The language used in lambda is node js.

Node js for AWS Lambda and Actions on google.

I am expecting token id in API result.

Comment: Please, post the code which you've already tried. It is impossible to solve your issue without fully understanding.

Comment: exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    // TODO implement
   console.log(callback);
   console.log(context);